# Is a function of bounded semivariation bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, bounded-variation

Let $X$ be a topological vector space and let $f:[a,b]\to X$. We say that $f$ is of *bounded semi-variation* in $[a,b]$ if the set $SV(f,[a,b])$ consisting of all the elements of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i[f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})]$$
where $a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=b$ and $|a_i|\le 1$, $a_i$ being complex numbers, is a bounded subset in $X.$

**Question.** With the above definition, is the set
$$f[a,b]=\{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}$$
a bounded set in $X$ whenever $f$ is of bounded semi-variation?

If the answer is yes, then in this case, we say that $f$ is bounded and I would be thankful if you can give me some ideas or tips to resolved the question. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ has finite semivariation, then there exist bounded set $B\subset X$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i[f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})]\in B
$$
for all $a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=b$ and $|a_i|\le 1$, $a_i$ being complex numbers.

Fix $x\in[a,b]$ and set $n=2$, $t_0=a$, $t_1=x$, $t_2=b$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$, then
$$
(f(x)-f(a))-(f(b)-f(x))\in B
$$
this means that
$$
f(x)\in 0.5(f(a)+f(b)+B)
$$
Since $x\in[a,b]$ is arbitrary
$$
f([a,b])\subset 0.5(f(a)+f(b)+B)
$$
The set in the rifght hand side is clearly bounded, hence so does $f([a,b])$.

Comment: I guess you are saying that $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i[f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})]\in B?$$

Comment: @juniven yes, exactly